# jQuery JSONP not calling the callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I am having some problem with jsonp and jquery.

This is my code -

```
var myCallback = function(data) {
  console.log(data);
};

$.ajax({
  url: my_url,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: 'callback',
  jsonpCallback: 'myCallback'
});
```

jQuery adds something like `?callback=myCallback&_=1340513330866` to my_url and the data returned from my_url is `myCallback('abcd')` - although in reality it will be returning some HTML code instead of the `abcd`.

Problem: `abcd` is not logged in console through `myCallback`. So what am i doing wrong ? I was under the impression that the data returned will be executed as it is inside script tags ?

Comment: could you post an example of the response you want

Comment: `myCallback` must be global... is it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you use your own function, then you have to explicitly declare it as **global**. For example:

```
window.myCallback = function(data) {
  console.log(data);
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LwuPL/)

---

**Explanation**

Every function that should be called in response to a successful JSONP request must be global. jQuery is doing this as well. This is because JSONP is nothing else than including a (dynamically generated (most of the time)) JavaScript file with a `<script>` tag, which only contains a function call.  Since each script is evaluated in global scope, the function that is called must be global as well.

Comment: @Felix - Thanks, the example you given helped me a lot. +10;

Answer (score 1):

1) move the single quote from the called method (as Umesh Aawte wrote)

2) make the callback global

3) your callback is a part of jQuery now so **this** is your way to get your datas

hereafter the solution: (using jQuery : v3.3.1, node : v6.10.0, express : v4.16.3

```
window.myCallback = function() {
  console.log(this.data);
}

$.ajax({
  url: my_url,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: 'myCallback',
  jsonpCallback: myCallback
});
```

that's all folks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove single quote from the called method this will work, Please check the code here,

```
var myCallback = function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    };

$.ajax({
  url: my_url,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: 'callback',
  jsonpCallback: myCallback
});
```

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bA84y/)

Comment: That won't work. From the documentation: *"As of jQuery 1.5, you can also use a function for this setting, in which case the value of jsonpCallback is **set to the return value of that function**."*. Your fiddle is not set up properly, so I wonder what it should demonstrate.

Comment: But when I tried it's working on sample I have also added a working fiddle you can check the fiddle I have added

Comment: As I said, I don't know what your demo is supposed to show. It only shows an alert with `undefined`... which proofs nothing. You did not even use the JSONP URL for the fiddle. If you have a look at the developer tools (Network tab, assuming Chrome) you will see that no request is made at all... the Ajax call does not take place. To be clear: Te alert appears because jQuery is calling the function you assign to  `jsonpCallback` **to get the callback name**, just as the documentation says. It is **not** called in response to a successful Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
$.getJSON(my_url, myCallback);
```

this will handle function scoping and looks much simpler