# ajax get json from web API but return error

Tags: ajax, api

I use ajax to get json from a web API as following.

The browser log shows that json result is extracted, but the page returned the error function: alert("Please try later").
[browser log image](http://chuantu.biz/t5/50/1489545176x2890174541.png) 
Is there anything wrong?

Thanks!

```
$.ajax({  
   url :"http://dgidb.genome.wustl.edu/api/v1/interactions.json", 
   type:"get",  
   async:false,  
   data: {genes: genes, interaction_sources: interaction_sources},
   dataType:"jsonp",
   jsonp:"callback",
   jsonpCallback:"message",
   success: function(data){  
      alert(data);
   },
   error: function(){  
      alert("Please try later");
   } 
});
```

Comment: Did you try to this?
data: {'genes': genes, 'interaction_sources': interaction_sources},
Hope genes and interaction_sources are variables.

Comment: Thanks Rishi. I just tried but returns the same error.

Comment: Your JSONResponse is not calling back. Refere to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175029/jquery-jsonp-not-calling-the-callback

Answer (score 0):

Remove dataType:"jsonp" or use dataType:"json"

Comment: Thanks Dushyantha. I just tried but it returns the same error.

Comment: Can you provide a image of your request header

Comment: [request header source](http://chuantu.biz/t5/50/1489556101x1822611262.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using your code I could not get it to work unless I added quotes around the "genes" and "interaction_sources".

If I access the url: http://dgidb.genome.wustl.edu/api/v1/interactions.json directly it says: **{"error":"You must enter at least one gene name to search!"}**

Perhaps instead of the "genes" and "interaction_sources" you should be using search parameters?

**EDIT:** if you could provide the API for the json you are trying to access we might be able to debug it?

```js
$("#runme").on("click", function() {
  RunMe();
});

function RunMe() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://dgidb.genome.wustl.edu/api/v1/interactions.json",
    type: "get",
    async: false,
    data: {
      genes: "genes",
      interaction_sources: "interaction_sources"
    },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: "callback",
    jsonpCallback: "message",
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Please try later");
    }
  });

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="runme">RUN ME!!!</button>
```

Comment: I feel sorry for the misleading. In the script, "genes" and "interaction_sources" are two variables, you could set the value of genes as "FLT1,MM1,FAKE", and set the value of interaction_sources as "TALC". [http://dgidb.genome.wustl.edu/api/v1/interactions.json?genes=FLT1,MM1,FAKE&interaction_sources=TALC](http://dgidb.genome.wustl.edu/api/v1/interactions.json?genes=FLT1,MM1,FAKE&interaction_sources=TALC) returns correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure API response date with **application/json** header

```html
{
  "matchedTerms": [],
  "unmatchedTerms": [
    {
      "searchTerm": "GENES",
      "suggestions": []
    }
  ]
}
```

This response's Content-Type would be application/json. I tried this is on POSTMAP manually and it worked. Just fixed the Content-Type header value.